# Is there any way dump an IBM Rational Synergy Database through Java?

Tags: java, cm-synergy

I was wondering if an API exist that would allow me to dump a synergy database through java. I can create an excel report through IBM Rational Change but it would be nice if there was a way to just send a CCMDB query to the server through java and generate a CSV or XML file and have it dumped locally. Any body know of a possible way to do that?

Comment: My comiserations on having to use Synergy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would doubt that something exists publicly. You can always call a command line ccm query from java and parse the output. I am working on a Python script that will do something similar, but it will be highly specific to my project DB setup (which is a mess).